# Prompt for Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

all.

I'm setting up content types for a modern SharePoint Online doc library in anticipation of a migration.

As there will be several content types to choose on upload, is there a way to set the default content type to blank/null value or to a read-only field prompt message?

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there is no OOB way to do that.

The first content type in "Change New Button Order" will be the default content type. There is no way to set the default content type to null/none or a read-only field.
[image]

Comment: One work-around I found is changing the library's default Documents content type to "Choose Content Type"-- read only and local to the library.  I don't know if there are negative ramifications for doing this...

At least I can filter by this.